# React Native animate problem adding translate X to interpolate

Tags: react-native, image, animation, interpolation

I am trying to learn how to animate things in react native. I have a few things working but now I want to use the translateX and scaleX etc.

I have this working which simply spins the image :

```
const spin = spinValue.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
})
```

and now I would like to use something like this to make the image bigger but I can not get it to work? :

```
transform: [
 {
  translateX: this.animatedValue.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [0, 120]
  })
```

I have tried but it doesnt work?

```
const spin = translateX: animatedValue.spinValue.interpolate({
```

This is not all of it just snippets of what I am trying. Am I doing it totally wrong or is it something else?

Any help would be appreciated.